How to select printer names and then print from each printer in pdf using C#?
I am struggling to print for each printer name, but i can with A4 size, yes i do get the value from the property in PrintToTermal method. But the issue i need to get Weight shown on the PDF as i am having in A4 size. In another words all the details user inserts from the form, they need to be displayed in printers. In this case Weight is not displayed. I need some help to improve the logic for both methods. PrintToThermal and PrintButton when user select any.
print click method
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string paths = "", appPath = "";
    try
    {
        if (ID > 0)
        {
            if (txtBatchNumber.Text == "" || txtNumberOfLabel.Text == "" || txtWeight.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill in all required information.", "Required Information");
                return;
            }
    
            DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("ID=" + ID);
            var name = dr[0]["Recipe_Name"].ToString();
            var description = dr[0]["Recipe_Description"].ToString();
        
            string reportName = "";
    
            string optionSelected = "";
            if (cboPrintOption.SelectedValue.ToString() == "1") //Thermal Printer Small
            {
                optionSelected = "ThermalSmall";
                reportName = Properties.Settings.Default.ReportNameSmallThermal;
            }
            else if (cboPrintOption.SelectedValue.ToString() == "2") //Thermal Printer Large 
            {
                optionSelected = "ThermalLarge";
                reportName = Properties.Settings.Default.ReportNameLargeThermal;
    
            }
            else if (cboPrintOption.SelectedValue.ToString() == "3") //A4
            {
                optionSelected = "A4";
                reportName = Properties.Settings.Default.ReportNameA4;
    
            }
    
            #region InsertPrintAudit
            string names = description;
            string concatName = string.Concat("M", name.Substring(1));
            int LabelID = 0;
            string weightDisplay = "Weight: " + txtWeight.Text;
            #endregion InsertPrintAudit
    
            CreateBarcodeDataTable();
    
            if (optionSelected == "A4")
            {
                if (cboPrinter.Text.Contains("ZDesigner"))
                {
                     MessageBox.Show("A4 cannot be printed to selected Printer. Please choose a different printer", "Invalid Printer");
                     return;
                }
                LabelID = 12345;
                for (int i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberOfLabel.Text); i++)
                {
                     if (DevEnvironment != '1')
                     LabelID = this.SavePrintingInfo(name, Convert.ToInt32(txtSeriesNumber.Text), txtBatchNumber.Text, Convert.ToDecimal(txtWeight.Text), concatName);
                     dtPrintedBarcode.Rows.Add("*" + LabelID.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0') + "*", names, txtBatchNumber.Text, name, weightDisplay, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                                                       );
    
                     }
    
                     if (DevEnvironment == '1')
                     {
                         appPath = Path.Combine(path, @"Report\" + reportName);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         appPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Report\" + reportName);
                     }
    
                     cry.Load(appPath);
                     cry.SetDataSource(dtPrintedBarcode);
                     crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cry;
    
                     string PrinterName = this.printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
                     cry.PrintOptions.PrinterName = PrinterName;
                     printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = cboPrinter.Text.ToString();
                     cry.Refresh();
                     cry.PrintOptions.PrinterName = cboPrinter.Text.ToString();
                     cry.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 1, 2);
    
                }
                else if (optionSelected == "ThermalSmall")
                {
                     PrintToThermal(LabelID, names, name, reportName, paths, appPath, concatName);
                     dtPrintedBarcode.Rows.Add("*" + LabelID.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0') + "*", names, txtBatchNumber.Text, name, weightDisplay, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                           ) ;
    
                }
                else if (optionSelected == "ThermalLarge")
                {
                    PrintToThermal(LabelID, names, name, reportName, paths, appPath, concatName);
                    dtPrintedBarcode.Rows.Add("*" + LabelID.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0') + "*", names, txtBatchNumber.Text, name, weightDisplay, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                }
                ClearAllInfo();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a record to print.", "Record");
            }
            txtSeriesNumber.Text = "";
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = null;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString() + " Path: " + Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\");
            if (ex.InnerException.ToString().Contains("cannot find the file"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Path:  " + appPath + " " + paths);
            }
        }
    }

print to thermal. printer names
public void PrintToThermal(int LabelID, string names, string name, string reportName, string paths, string appPath, string concatName)
{
    LabelID = 123456;
    string weightDisplay = "Weight: " + txtWeight.Text;
    CreateBarcodeDataTable();
    for (int i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberOfLabel.Text); i++)
    {
        if (DevEnvironment == '1')
        {
            appPath = Path.Combine(path, @"Report\" + reportName);
        }
        else
        {
            LabelID = this.SavePrintingInfo(name, Convert.ToInt32(txtSeriesNumber.Text), txtBatchNumber.Text, Convert.ToDecimal(txtWeight.Text), concatName);
            appPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Report\" + reportName);
        }
    
        dtPrintedBarcode.Rows.Add("*" + LabelID.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0') + "*", names, txtBatchNumber.Text, weightDisplay, concatName, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                    
        cry.Load(appPath);
        cry.SetDataSource(dtPrintedBarcode);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cry;
    
        // Default printer
        // string PrinterName = this.printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
        // cry.PrintOptions.PrinterName = PrinterName;
        printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = cboPrinter.Text.ToString();
        cry.Refresh();
        cry.PrintOptions.PrinterName = cboPrinter.Text.ToString();
        cry.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 1, 2);
    
        dtPrintedBarcode.Rows.Clear();
    }
    cry.SetDataSource(dtAllPrintedBarcodes);
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cry;
    cry.Refresh();
}


The implication is that there is a problem with the DataTable and / or "weight" column; and the weight value is not being added to the DataRow. I'd review the CreateBarcodeDataTable() method and the sequence of columns.
